# JDBC delete rows in db with specific timestamp

Tags: java, mysql, date, jdbc

I have a database in which I am saving messages with tiemstamps. I have table created with this code:

```
CREATE TABLE messages (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    msgid VARCHAR(64) UNIQUE,
    payload TEXT,
    sender VARCHAR(255),
    cur_timestamp TIMESTAMP(3)
);
```

This all works perfectly. However, now I am trying to delete some rows with timestamp older than some specified by user. This is done in Java part of my system like this:

```
// get current timestamp
Date date = new Date();
// timestamp has to be in the same format as in database
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss.SSS");
String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
System.out.println("Current time: " + formattedDate);

// subtract desired time
if (msgOld.equals("hour")) {
  date.setTime(date.getTime() - ONE_HOUR_MILLISCONDS);
  formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
} else if (msgOld.equals("day")) {
  date.setTime(date.getTime() - ONE_DAY_MILLISCONDS);
  formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
}
```

This, too, works fine - the constants look like this: `final long ONE_HOUR_MILLISCONDS = 60 * 60 * 1000;`

The only problem is that I dont know how to write the query in JDBC. I tried doing this:

```
// prepare query
String query;
if (msgOld.equals("all")) {
    query = "TRUNCATE TABLE messages";
} else {
    query = "DELETE FROM messages WHERE cur_timestamp < " + date + ";";
}
```

but it says I have an error in my SQL statement (the second one, the one with TRUNCATE works fine). I tried putting `formattedDate` instead of `date` in the statement, too.

Whats wrong with it (probably something really simple - maybe difference between `java.util.Date` and SQL timestamp...)? Thanks for any tips!

EDIT: Thanks for all responses... I have rewritten the code so it uses prepared statement like this:

```
// prepare query
        String query;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

        try {
            if (msgOld.equals("all")) {
                query = "TRUNCATE TABLE messages";
                pstmt=conn.prepareStatement(query);
            } else {
            query = "DELETE FROM messages WHERE cur_timestamp < ?;";
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            pstmt.setString(1, timestamp.toString());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            pstmt.execute();

            System.out.println("Successfully deleted messages.");
            pstmt.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error with db query.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

but I am still getting SQL exception (even if I convert date to timestamp and like this `Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime());` and use it in the satement)

Comment: Why don't you use prepared statements?

Comment: with prepared statement : 
Instead of using java.util. You can use java.sql.date.valueOf("2016-11-06"); use this with prepared statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot just concatenate `java.util.Date` objects into query string. That's wrong.

Better use `PreparedStatement` for this kind of things.

Take a look at this tutorial for [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Answer (score 0):

exactly as @Funtik said preparedStatement could be used.
See this link [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-to-insert-timestamp-value-in-preparedstatement/)

it would not exactly sove your problem but you will get a clear idea.